# currentdb execute does not insert

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having trouble with Access VBA. I made the following code to insert some data to my SQL DB.

```
Private Sub btnFilmKijkenKlant_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO watchhistory (movie_id, customer_mail_address, watch_date, price, invoiced)  VALUES (" & movie_id.Value & ", '" & Me.txtEmail & "',  Date(),'" & price.Value & "', '0')"

End Sub
```

When the user hits the button I want some data to be transferred to the DB. 
I don't get any errors but it just doesn't insert...

I made txtEmail field for testing. I got an e-mail field in another form that I want to use as customer_mail_address.

When I include the *dbFailOnError* option with `CurrentDb.Execute`, Access complains *"ODBC Call failed"*, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you confirmed that *btnFilmKijkenKlant_Click* actually runs?  If so, include the *dbFailOnError* to see if there is a silent problem such as a primary key violation: `CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT ...", dbFailOnError`

Comment: As suggested by @HansUp, you should get into the habit of using `, dbFailOnError` unless you are *certain* that you want to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries to be able to fail silently under certain conditions.

Comment: Also, if you revise your procedure to use a parameter query, you won't have to bother with quotes in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Hello HansUp, I did a msgBox "Hi" to test if it runs. Well the buttons seems to run i had a popup with Hi. I added ur dbFailOnError and i got the following 

It says ODBC Call failed... i dont know why.
'
Private Sub btnFilmKijkenKlant_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO watchhistory (movie_id, customer_mail_address, watch_date, price, invoiced)  VALUES (" & movie_id.Value & ", '" & Me.txtEmail & "',  Date(),'" & price.Value & "', '0')", dbFailOnError

End Sub
'

Comment: @HansUp Well im not used to work with acces. I'm trying to find the datasheet view. But i can see all data in the watchhistory table if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @HansUp i can add new records as long it is the date of today or more.

Comment: Finally! I'm getting an error. It is because of a chck constraint to check if the watch_date is today or more... I think i did something wrong there i guess... I deleted the constraint now i can add data to the watchhistory table. omg i would have never found this error without your help!

Comment: Great!  Please submit an answer describing your solution.  Later when the system allows, you can mark it accepted.  I trust you see the benefit of `dbFailOnError` now.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim db as Database
Set db = CurrentDb()
db.execute(......)
```

Comment: @HansUp helped me out already with this problem. This answer wouldnt fix my error.